# How to replace date on a jQuery countdown script with a PHP variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can this script is modified to accept a php variable instead in the place of writing `date:"august 12, 2011 23:59"` ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "august 12, 2011 23:59",
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("Completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a php variable"? Do you want to make an ajax call to your server to send you the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "<?php echo $variable; ?>",
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("Completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "<?=$myvariable?>",
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("Completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your js parsed by php first?  if so its just a matter of passing the correct date format.

to get the same format as above you can use

```
strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M");
```

So your code block would look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "<?php echo strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M");?>",
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("Completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to format the date as per your need on the server side itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "<? =date("Y/m/d") ?>",
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("Completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is an AJAX call, you should do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('path/to/php/date', function(date) {      
        $("#time").countdown({
            date: date,
            onComplete: function( event ){
                $(this).html("Completed");
            },
            leadingZero: true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Make sure that the php script at "path/to/php/date" returns the date you want.